Как рисуется ConstraintLayout?
На одном из собеседований задали такой вопрос. Как рисуется(рендерится) ConstraintLayout?
Я конечно после собеса посмотрел документацию, но такой инфы нет. Где почитать об этом?

Предположу: как и любой другой ViewGroup - по древовидной иерархии потомков состоящих из ViewGroup и View, и с учетом z координаты, а также elevation.
